# How to set values for structure members in Base class that remain the same in the Derived class

Tags: c++

With reference to the following code:

```
class Base
{   
public:
struct DataType
{
    public:
      long double var1;
      int begin;
      int stop;

      inline DataType() {}
      inline long double get_var1() {return this->var1;}    
      inline int get_begin() {return this->begin;}  
      inline int get_stop() {return this->stop;}

      inline void set_var1(long double var1) {this->var1=var1;} 
      inline void set_begin(int begin) {this->begin=begin;} 
      inline void set_stop(int stop) {this->stop=stop;}
};

inline Base() {}
virtual ~Base() {}  

protected:
virtual void funct()
{

}

void execute()
{
   // How can I set a value of begin here?
   funct(); 
   // How can I set a value of stop here?   
}
};

class Derived:public Base
{
    DataType dt;

    public:
    inline Derived() 
    {
    this->dt.set_var1(0.005);       
    }   
    inline ~Derived() {}

    protected:
    void funct();
};

void Derived::funct()
{
    //Some implementation
}
```

Apart from this, there is a lot more code and somewhere Derived is instantiated and execute() is invoked. What I want to do here is that I want to set values for begin and stop inside the execute method in the Base class just before and after the invocation of the funct() method respectively (as shown using comments) so that whenever we create an object for Derived, say obj_derived, it has the same values for begin and stop as set inside the execute().

Thank you very much for any replies.

Comment: Implement `Derived::funct()` so that it does what you require. But your base class has no data members, only the derived type does. Maybe that is what is confusing you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Base` class definition:

```
struct DataType{
...
} dt;    //now there is a member 'dt' of type 'struct DataType'
```

and in `execute` method;

```
void execute()
{
   this->dt.set_begin(1);
   funct(); 
   this->dt.set_stop(1);
}
```

also in `Derived` class definition comment out:

```
//DataType dt;
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. If I do it this way, I can still set a value for var1 in the Derived class by dt.set_var1(0.005) right?

Comment: Yes, as soon as you define your structure `dt` as `public` or `protected` in your base class, it is inherited and accessible in derived classes.

Answer (score 1):

The base class doesn't have a member of type `DataType`. It's only defined in `Derived`.

You can move the declaration of `dt` from `Derived` to `Base`. Doesn't it solve your problem?